# signature generator - how to remove an element in javascript if two fields are empty

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a signature block for my company and testing out the validation.

1. When only mobile is entered, it works fine
2. When only fax is entered, it works fine
3. when BOTH mobile and fax are omitted, it for some reason still shows the "C:" and the " | " for mobile phone

Do i need to create an if / then with both?

https://codepen.io/jggrs/pen/RMNVLZ?editors=1100

```
<html>


    <head>
    <style>
    #form_box{
    border: 2px solid #2c2c59;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #dadada;
      }  

    #outgoing{
    border: 1px solid #df4540;
    padding: 20px;
      }

    #reply{
    border: 1px solid #df4540;
    padding: 20px;
      }  
    </style>




    <script type="text/JavaScript">


    //first and last name validation

    function validateForm()
    {  
      var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["flname"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("First & Last Name - Must be Filled Out!");
            return false;
            }

    //title validation
        var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["title"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("Title - Must be Filled Out!");
            return false;
        }

    //office phone # validation
       var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["office"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("Office Phone # - Must be Filled Out!");
            return false;
        } 

    //email validaton 
      var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["email"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("E-mail - Must be Filled Out!");
            return false;
        }


    //fax check + disappear!
     var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["fax"].value;
          if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("faxy").remove();
            document.getElementById("pipe2").remove();
            document.getElementById("faxy2").remove();
            document.getElementById("pipe5").remove();
            return false;
        }     

    //mobile phone check + disappear!
     var x = document.forms["sigForm"]["mobile"].value;
          if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("cell").remove();
            document.getElementById("pipe1").remove();
            document.getElementById("cell2").remove();
            document.getElementById("pipe4").remove();
            return false;
        }  


    //end bracket function  
    } 

    //
    function getOption()

    {
    //first and last name 
    var firstlast = document.getElementById("firstlast").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_firstlast'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= firstlast
    });

    //title
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_title'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= title
    });  


    //office
    var office = document.getElementById("office").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_office'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= office
    });  


    //mobile
    var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_mobile'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= mobile
    });  


    //fax
    var fax = document.getElementById("fax").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_fax'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= fax
    });  

    //email
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var list = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('display_email'));
    list.forEach(function(item){
    item.innerHTML= email
    });  


    //addresses dropdown 

    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('display_address');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].innerHTML = address;
    }





    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <h1 style="font-family: arial;">Signature Block Generator - Federal Heath</h1>

    How to create your own signature block (must use internet explorer):
    <ol>
      <li>Fill out the form below</li>
      <li>Copy entire signature</li>
      <li>Paste into outlook</li>
      <li>View video on right if you have any issues</li>


      </ol><br />

    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px;"> <iframe width="300" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWlGf0noxOQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br /><br /></div>


    <div id="form_box">
    <form onsubmit="return !!(validateForm() & false)" name="sigForm">
    First and Last Name: <input type="text" name="flname" id = "firstlast"><br /><br />
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" id = "title"><br /><br />
    Office Phone #: <input name="office" type ="text" id ="office"><br /><br />
    Mobile #: <input name="mobile" type ="text" id ="mobile"><span style="font-style: italic;color: #646464;"> optional</span><br /><br />
    Fax #: <input name="fax" type ="text" id ="fax"><span style="font-style: italic;color: #646464;"> optional</span><br /><br />
    E-mail: <input name="email" type ="text" id ="email"><br /><br />  



    Address:
    <select id="address" class="address">
    <option>Select Your Location</option>
    <option>160 West Carmel Drive, Suite 236 | Carmel, IN 46032</option>
    <option>198 Haven Lane | Idaho Falls, ID 83404</option>
    <option>601 Royal Crest Way | Brandon, FL 33511</option>
    <option>625 Market Street, Suite 600 | Knoxville, TN 37902</option>
    <option>668 Harris Road | Coldwater, MS 38618</option>
    <option>1020 Pittsburgh Dr., Suite A | Delaware OH 43015</option>
    <option>1128 Beville Road, Suite E | Daytona Beach, FL 32114</option>
    <option>1234 San Francisco | San Antonio, TX 78201</option>
    <option>1251 Washington Street, Suite 245 | Grafton, WI 53024</option>
    <option>1500 North Bolton Street | Jacksonville, TX 75766</option>
    <option>1840 Oakdale Avenue | Racine, WI 53406</option>
    <option>10425 Old Alabama Road Connector Suite 102 | Alpharetta, GA 30022</option>
    <option>2300 State Highway 121 | Euless, TX 76039</option>
    <option>3900 West Dewey Drive | Las Vegas NV 89118</option>
    <option>3609 Ocean Ranch Blvd., Suite 204 | Oceanside, CA 92056</option>
    <option>4046 N. Goldenrod Road, #269 | Winter Park FL 62792</option>
    <option>4602 North Avenue | Oceanside, CA 92056</option>
    <option>6040 Dutchmans Lane, Suite 300 | Louisville, KY 40205</option>
    <option>7501 South Quincy Street, Suite #175 | Willowbrook, IL 60527</option>
    <option>12704 Dupont Circle | Tampa FL 33626</option>
    <option>15534 West Hardy Road, Suite 200 | Houston, TX 77060</option>  
    </select>

      <br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="getOption()" value="Make My Signature" >
    </form>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <h2 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;">OUTGOING SIGNATURE</h2>  
    <div id="outgoing">
    <!--OUTGOING EMAIL-->  



    <!--NAME AND TITLE-->
    <span class = "display_firstlast" style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16.5px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

      <span style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16.5px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span> 

      <span class = "display_title" style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16.5px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <br />


    <!--OFFICE-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">O: </span> 

    <!--OFFICE PHONE-->  
    <span class = "display_office" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <!--PIPE-->
    <span id="pipe1" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span>  

    <!--CELL PHONE-->
    <span id="cell" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">C:</span>  

    <!--MOBILE-->  
    <span class = "display_mobile" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <!--PIPE-->
    <span id="pipe2" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span>  

    <!--FAX-->
    <span id="faxy" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Fax: </span>   

    <!--FAX PHONE-->
    <span class = "display_fax" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <!--PIPE-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span> 

    <!--EMAIL-->
    <span class = "display_email" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span><br />

    <!--<a href="http://www.federalheath.com"><img src="http://www.federalheath.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/natasha_photo_taller.png"></a><br />-->

    <!--JUST LOGO-->

    <a href="http://www.federalheath.com"><img src="http://www.federalheath.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/federal_heath.png" alt="Federal Heath"></a><br />



     <!--ADDRESS-->
    <span class = "display_address" style="color: #848484;font-size: 9px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 2px;"></span><br /><br />



    <!--LINES OF BUSINESS-->

     <a style="text-decoration: none;color: 2c2c59;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="http://www.federalheath.com/signage">SIGNAGE</a>

    <!--PIPE-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">|</span>

    <a style="text-decoration: none;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="http://www.federalheath.com/maintenance/">MAINTENANCE</a>

    <!--PIPE #2-->
    <span id="pipe2"style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">|</span>

    <a style="text-decoration: none;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="http://www.federalheath.com/specialty-contracting/">SPECIALTY CONTRACTING</a>

    <!--PIPE #3-->
    <span id="pipe3" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">|</span>

    <a style="text-decoration: none;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="http://www.federalheath.com/digital-signage/"> DIGITAL SIGNAGE</a>

    <!--PIPE #4-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">|</span>

     <a style="text-decoration: none;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="http://www.federalheath.com/printed-graphics/">PRINTED GRAPHICS</a><br />


    <!--COMPANY SLOAGAN-->
    <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #848484;font-style: italic; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">We help businesses connect and engage with their customers.</span><br /><span><a href="http://www.federalheath.com" style="font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">VISIT OUR WEBSITE</span></a>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />




    <!--REPLY EMAIL-->  
    <h2 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;">REPLY SIGNATURE</h2>  
    <div id="reply"> 


    <!--NAME AND TITLE-->
    <span class = "display_firstlast" style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

      <span style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span> 

      <span class = "display_title" style="color: #2c2c59; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <br />


    <!--OFFICE-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">O: </span> 

    <!--OFFICE PHONE-->  
      <span class = "display_office" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <!--PIPE #4-->
    <span id="pipe4" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span>  

    <!--CELL PHONE-->
    <span id="cell2" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">C:</span>  

    <!--MOBILE-->  
    <span class = "display_mobile" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span>

    <!--PIPE #2-->
    <span id="pipe5" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span>  

    <!--FAX-->
    <span id="faxy2" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Fax: </span>   

    <!--FAX PHONE-->
    <span class = "display_fax" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span><br />

    <!--PIPE #3-->
    <span style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"> | </span>   

    <!--EMAIL-->
    <span class = "display_fax" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2c2c59; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span><br />



     <!--ADDRESS-->
    <span class = "display_address" id="paddress" style="color: #2c2c59;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 2px;"></span><br /><br />

      </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to validate data before displaying it in UI. You can achieve this in many ways, and one of them is to check if data exists, then display, otherwise you do not need to display your span elements. You can hide those by applying the css `display` property.

```
display: none;
```